# when i click on text its checkbox automatically checkbox must checked in visualforce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, dynamic-visualforce, ajax

```
<apex:page controller="Apexclassforaccandcheck">
<apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:dataTable value="{!acw}" var="aa">
            <apex:column><apex:inputCheckbox rendered="true" value="{!aa.checked}">
                <apex:outputText value="{!aa.nam}"/></apex:inputCheckbox>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:dataTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form></apex:page>
```

### Controller

```
public class Apexclassforaccandcheck{
Public List<Account> acc{set;get;}
Public List<accwrap> acw{set;get;}
Public Apexclassforaccandcheck() {
    acc=[select id,name,phone from account];
    acw=new List<accwrap>();
    acw.clear();
    for(Account a:acc){
        acw.add(new accwrap(a.name,a.id));
    }
}
Public class accwrap{
    Public String nam{set;get;}
    Public String ids{set;get;}
    Public Boolean checked{set;get;}
    Public accwrap(String n,String i){
        nam=n;
        ids=i;
        checked=false;
    }
}}
```

### whine i click on text checkbox should enable

[image: whine i click on text checkbox should enable]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use html `label` and `for` attribute as below.

```
<label for="{!$Component['cbox']}">{!aa.nam}</label>
<apex:inputCheckbox id="cbox" rendered="true" value="{!aa.checked}">
```

Label for and checkbox id should match. Since visualforce changes Id attribute at runtime we use `$Component` to get that id.

Comment: visualforce page throwing error "Literal value is required for attribute id in <apex:inputCheckbox> in Apexclassforaccandcheckvf " error in <apex:inputCheckbox id="{!aa.ids}" rendered="true" value="{!aa.checked}"/>`

Comment: Changed answer. This actually works but have to check for repeat

Comment: thank you some mutch it working perfectly

Comment: Pls mark as solved if solved